# Can I search You Tube via API for video's that will not give me restricted playback?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iframe, youtube

I am developing an iPhone app with the Youtube API. I am playing the video inline.  Is there a way I can exclude from the youtube search video's that give the message "this video contains content from WMG." It is restricted from playback.